# conditionally enabling constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, conditional-statements

Here is how I can conditionally enable a constructor  of a class :

```
struct Foo
{

    template<class T>
    Foo( T* ptr, boost::enable_if<is_arithmetic<T> >::type* = NULL )
    {}

};
```

I would like to know why I need to do the enabling via a dummy parameter. Why can I not just write :

```
struct Foo
{
    template<class T>
    Foo( boost::enable_if<is_arithmetic<T>, T>::type* = NULL )
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can on any other function but the constructor, because then you can modify the function name including the template arguments.

```
Foo foo;
foo.Method<T>();
```

With a constructor, though, the constructor name never appears in your expression, so there's no place to explicitly put the template parameter.  You have to deduce it from an argument.

```
Foo<T> foo; // no good, assumes the type Foo is a template, not its constructor
Foo* pfoo = new Foo<T>(); // same problem

Foo foo((T*)0); // ok, deduced
Foo* pfoo = new Foo((T*)0); // same
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the issue is to make sure that template argument deduction succeeds. This is done either by explicitly instantiating the template with the type - foo.Method<T> or to make Method take an argument which allows deduction - 
    template<class U>
    void Method(U* ptr, boost::enable_if<is_arithmetic<U> >::type * = NULL)
    {}

Comment: @MK: Yes, with most member functions you have the option.  With constructors, there's no way to explicitly specify the template arguments.

Comment: @MK: With other functions, `enable_if` goes nicely onto the return value, so as not to disturb template argument deduction. Alas, constructors don't have a return type. OTOH, nobody will take the address of the constructor function and therefore nobody will be bothered about that "hidden" additional argument.